# using process editor Making workitem field readonly for specific TFS group

Tags: tfs

I am using TFS 2013 and using the process template I am adding new "Readonly" rule to a field then in the "Not" field I chose *[project]\My Team* so it should be readonlt for all other groups except *My team* ,now if I open any workitem from this type from within the VS I found the field readonly!! however if I opened it from the web portal the field is editable as expected but if I tried to change the value of this field I got this error 
 "TF237165: Team Foundation could not update the work item because of a validation error on the server. This may happen because the work item type has been modified or destroyed, or you do not have permission to update the work item."
but changing and saving any other field is done without any errors,I tried to run [rebuildcache](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/reference/witadmin/rebuild-client-cache) command t clear any client cache only to get the same exact result

Comment: Do all the members in your team have the same problem? have you tried with a new client? Just try to clean the caches both for IE and VS in your client, then try it again. Besides, please note that "Do not use READONLY with the EMPTY element because EMPTY also makes a field read-only. If you combine these elements, results will be inconsistent."

Comment: Yes,multpile users from multiple machines got the same error when they try to update the workitem-actually except one single machine!-and I only added READONLY rule to the field

Comment: I tested at my side, everything works correctly. So, please delete the "Readonly" rule and check if there are any exceptions for your teams. then add the 'Readonly' rule again. or you can try another project to check if it has the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the thing, I left it for couple of days and when I returned to it I found everything is working like a charm ,so I guess it is Time that heals all wounds