# TFS shows old cached team members in "Assigned To" field

Tags: tfs

I'm using TFS 2013 and the process editor templates. I am trying to add an "allowed values" rule for the "Assigned To" standard field so I entered "[Project]\Some TFS Team" in the the ListItem popup hopping that only members from this team will appear in the dropdownlist suggested values of this field. 
 Unfortunately the list showed old team members of this team and no matter I added or removed members to and from this team the dropdownlist keeps showing only the old data.

Here are the steps I tried to clear that cache:
1-restart everything (TFS, my machine, TFS server)
2-remove and re-add the rule
3-run `witadmin rebuildcache` from my machine
4-delete C:\Users\ ...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache folder

What else should I look for to make the TFS responsive?
Note:
The same old list also appears in the field in the TFS web access.

Comment: Are the team members being managed directly through TFS, or through active directory? When you say "old", do you mean "old" as in "weeks/months old", or "hours" old?

Comment: Thanks Daniel,no al are managed using TFS only and I mean by "old" more than one week old

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Andy-MSFT it looked like it took years from me to figure out what was the issue- maybe because I didn't logged into the TFS server itself -as I ran TfsSyncIdentities.exe tool to enforce the AD sync then run it again with /status option to check I found that it didn't run , only then I know that the *Job agent* service is stopped!!, and just after I restarted it everything worked as dreams and TFS responding to all the changes 
note:
I had to stop it again because the TFS became toooooo slow when the job agent was running 
Thanks Andy for you help and support

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the default **ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE** and **VALIDUSER** rule.

Just change the **Assigned to** filed context as below:

```
  <FIELD name="Assigned To" refname="System.AssignedTo" type="String" syncnamechanges="true" reportable="dimension">
    <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
     <LISTITEM value="[Project]\Team0720" />
    </ALLOWEDVALUES>
  </FIELD>
```

---

**Update:**

Please try below items to narrow down the issue:

- TFS doesn’t reflect changes in the AD immediately, you can try to
  force sync the changes, See [Neno’s blog](https://blogs.msmvps.com/vstsblog/2011/02/17/force-tfs-to-sync-with-active-directory/) post on the issue with a
  tool TfsSyncIdentities.exe as solutions. And this article to [synchronize TFS users with AD](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24305.how-to-synchronize-tfs-users-with-ad-active-directory.aspx) for your reference.
- Try to create a new team, then add several
  members to the team, then check the rule with this new team.
- Have a check for other work item types, whether they have the same issue.
- Have a check for another team project, to check if it works.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Andy for your answer butI exported the xml template file of the workitem toI examine the "Assigned To" field node but I found it the same exact as the node you posted -of course except for the team name- so I think the field is defined correctly but there is something else in the TFS that makes it insists on the old nonexistent now list !!

Comment: @WaleedAly Please try to create a new team, then add several members to the team, then check the rule with this new team. Also try to force sync, See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @Andy-MSFT  and sorry for the delay,
the workaround mentioned in the post-removing the security group and re-adding it or creating a new team -will not work in my case because I also have issue in TFS recognizing the name of any newly added group as an input in the fields Rules -check my post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44955488/using-process-editor-making-workitem-field-readonly-for-specific-tfs-group?noredirect=1#comment76979219_44955488

Comment: I tried TfsSyncIdentities tool and after running it it gave me the message "Identity synchronization job was queued with high priority"  but when I ran it at end of day again with "\status" option to check its last running time it gave me the last running date as last 31 May 
 and Yes the same behaviour exists in different workitem types and using different team names and in different TFS projects

Comment: @WaleedAly It should be the SYNC issue, just as you mentioned in your another thread, left it for couple of days and everything is working like a charm, you can also try following this article to [synchronize TFS users with AD](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24305.how-to-synchronize-tfs-users-with-ad-active-directory.aspx)

Comment: the users that don't appear in the field ddl are not new AD users, they are old ones just added to another different old  TFS team,so I am not sure if it is something has to do with AD syncing, also I already left it for ore than week now with no result  I am afraid it is something bigger than sync issue may be something bigger than all of us :D

Comment: @WaleedAly What about the new collection and new team project ? if new collection has the same issue, need to think about the AD